# Permissions for non-htdocs directory

Tags: centos, permissions, apache-httpd

I have created a folder outside of my htdocs directory as a means of adding extra security for downloadable digital goods to be sold from within a Magento storefront; so my question is: what permissions should I set for this non-htdocs directory ("digitalgoods")?

**Ownership:**

```
[parent]/htdocs apache:apache
[parent]/digitalgoods apache:apache
```

I currently have the "digitalgoods" folder set to 770. Does the PUBLIC need read or execute permissions to this folder if the web application will be pulling and serving these files via unique links??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With owner apache and group apache you should be ok with permissions 550 (the webserver doesn't need to modify the files, only be able to read them). The files will be accessed by users through the webserver anyways. However, in this case it doesn't really matter much, since the only other people on your system are system users, and I don't think you care about them accessing the files.

You probably would want to use a proper security mechanism. Even though the links might be unique, a crawler might still discover them, bypassing your business model. Also customers can share links with others, allowing them to download your files without paying. You will probably want to tie the download to the Magento session or authentication.